# how to show top 5 customer id in color or any python script in spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have cross table as shown in the attachment.

I used "color by" property to show top 5 electronics values.

I would like to show top 5 customer id(vertical axis) also in a color representation.

Can any one help me on this.

Kindly give me idea how to show top 5 customer id in color or any python script.

Regards
Naveen

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a new Calculated Column using the [`Rank()` function](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_ranking_functions.htm) coupled with a Limit By expression can handle this for you.

1. create a new Caluclated Column called `[Rank]` with the expression `Rank([column])`
2. on the visualization properties, on the **Data** page, where it says **Limit Data by Expression**, use the expression `[Rank] <=5`